# Node.js serving a Raphael.js script

Tags: node.js, raphael

I'm trying to serve a HTML page with raphael.js script inside using node.js.

My index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Raphael  testing html</title>    
<script  src="raphael-min.js"></script>  
<script>
    // Initialize container when document is loaded
    window.onload = function () {
        paper = Raphael(0, 0, 640, 720, "container");
        paper.circle(100,100,50).attr('fill','red');
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my server.js file is:

```
var httpServer = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

var httpServer = httpServer.createServer(function(request, response) {
 console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
 response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.end(index);
return;
});

httpServer.listen(8080, function() {});
```

Running the index.html file within a browser - works fine (ie., draws a circle). However, when trying to serve this using node:

```
$ node server.js
```

I get no circle when pointing my browser to localhost:8080/
Instead I get the following error in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:        
"http://localhost:8080/raphael-min.js". localhost/:6
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :8080/raphael-min.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined localhost/:12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

these modules can make your routing job easy: [express](http://expressjs.com/) and [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect).

Your code is fine, but your http server ONLY send the info with `'Content-Type': 'text/html'`

and the browser takes your `js` as `html`.

Here you have a gist with a example static node server:

https://gist.github.com/jmingov/5894964

And here express info about static content.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use